# ERROR: login passphrase is incorrect(ecryptfs-utils)

Tags: linux

I am trying to create encrypted private folder. When I run the following command

```
ecryptfs-setup-private
```

I am asked for my login passphrase which returns

```
ERROR: Your login passphrase is incorrect.
```

I have tried with my login password but still not working, What can I do?

Comment: Any thoughts about this problem? (having troubles at the moment)